# multi-bar plot of multiple categories

Tags: python, seaborn, catplot, grouped-bar-chart

I have a data frame that  basically is   a list of  Technicians and several categories that have been evaluated in their work (value 1 for passed evaluation, 0 for not passed). Each  technician is repeated for every evaluation.

in a dictionary form it would be [ {"Name":"A","cat1":1,"cat2":0},{"Name":"A","cat1":1,"cat2":1},{"Name": "B", "cat1":0, "cat2":1} ]

I want to create a chart, like a cat plot, where each  technician  has a group of bars each bars representing the number of correct evaluations of that category.

Do I need to reform all my dataset to do that? I know one can use the "hue" parameter to  create bar groups, but that separate one data attribute into multiple  columns, I want to make a column for each attribute. is there a way to do that, or I need to  reformat my dataset completely for that?

Comment: You could transform the dataframe to "long form" via `pd.melt`, and then use the 'Name' as `x=`, the 'variable' as `hue=` and the 'value' as `y=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `hue`, Seaborn prefers the data in "long form".  You can use `sns.barplot` with `estimator=sum` to calculate the total number of correct evaluations.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"Name": "A", "cat1": 1, "cat2": 0},
                   {"Name": "A", "cat1": 1, "cat2": 1},
                   {"Name": "B", "cat1": 0, "cat2": 1}])
df_long = df.melt(id_vars="Name", var_name='Category', value_name='Correct')
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
ax = sns.barplot(data=df_long, x='Name', y='Correct', hue='Category', estimator=sum, ci=None)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot on long form dataframe]